# Mix synchronous and asynchronous methods for HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

On [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx) I read:

> Your application cannot mix synchronous and asynchronous methods for a
>   particular request. If you call the BeginGetRequestStream method, you
>   must use the BeginGetResponse method to retrieve the response.

Is the opposite also true? If I call `BeginGetResponse` to read the response asynchronously should I also use `BeginGetRequestStream` to write the request?

My requests are small (100-1000 chars), the response can be large.
[This post](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jeffreyr/archive/2009/02/08/httpwebrequest-its-request-stream-and-sending-data-in-chunks.aspx) by Jeffrey Richter seems to say that in the case of a small payload it can be done synchronously (and without setting the `ContentLength` property). Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

technically no, you *can* synchronously send a request and process the response asyncrhonously and vice vera depending on your requirements but it's generally not recommended. For consistency, pick an approach that best meets your needs and implement both the request/response using the same approach

An example where you might mix approaches is when you send, say, a request for a report that may take some time to complete. You want to send the request synchronously as you want to make sure the request is fully sent before continuing (eg, accounting for connection problem if sent from a windows app), but process the response asynchronously as you don't want to tie up the UI while you're waiting for the response to come back. Even then though, I'd still recommend being consistent on your approach for both the send/receive.

Comment: Thanks DiskJunky, I agree with you but why msdn it's so categorical?

Comment: primarily I think it's from a maintenance point of view. It's easier for someone coming along after and looking at your code to understand one approach rather than two. Simplicity and ease of reading is always part of an elegant solution. As for MSDN, they have to recommend a "best practice" approach to help foster good coding and design